# Poynting vector and plane waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, power, poynting-vector

Suppose the electromagnetic field at a point is a superposition to two plane waves $(\vec E_1, \vec H_1)$ and $(\vec E_2, \vec H_2)$.  If the two plane-waves have different frequencies,  the (time-averaged)Poynting vector is given by
$$\frac{1}{2} \space \left\{\vec E_1 \times \vec H_1^* \space + \space \vec E_2 \times \vec H_2^*\right\}$$
If the two waves have the same frequency and same direction of propagation,  the answer would change to
$$\frac{1}{2} \space \left(\vec E_1 + \vec E_2\right) \times \left(\vec H_1 + \vec H_2\right)^*$$
If the two waves have the same frequency but different directions of propagation,  then what is the right formula for (average) Poynting vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If plane wave linearly polarized in direction $\hat e$ has propagation vector $\mathbf k = k \hat k$, where $\hat k$ denotes a unit vector, it can be written as
$$\mathbf E = \hat e E^0  e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r)} \tag{1}$$
$$\mathbf H = \hat h H^0 e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r)}\tag{2}$$
where the unit vector $\hat h$ is defined as $\hat h = \hat k \times \hat e$ and $H^0 =\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_0}{\mu_0}}E^0$.

Now let two plane waves move in the directions $\mathbf k_{1,2} = \hat k_{1,2}$ but have the same frequency and wave number:
$$\mathbf E_{1,2} = \hat e_{1,2} E^0_{1,2}  e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k_{1,2}\cdot  \mathbf r)} \tag{3}$$
$$\mathbf H_{1,2} = \hat h_{1,2} H^0_{1,2} e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k_{1,2} \cdot \mathbf r)}\tag{4} $$

The Poynting vector of the sum of the two waves is:
$$\mathbf S = (\mathbf E_1+\mathbf E_2)\times (\mathbf H^*_1+\mathbf H^*_2)\\
=(\hat e_1 E^0_1  e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k_1 \cdot \mathbf r)} +\hat e_2 E^0_2  e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k_2 \cdot \mathbf r)} )\times 
(\hat h_1 H^{0*}_1  e^{\mathfrak j (-\omega t + \mathbf k_1 \cdot \mathbf r)} +\hat h_2 H^{0*}_2  e^{\mathfrak j (-\omega t + \mathbf k_2 \cdot \mathbf r)} )
\tag{5}$$
Expand (5):
$$\mathbf S 
=\hat e_1\times \hat h_1  E^0_1H^{0*}_1 +\hat e_2\times \hat h_2  E^0_2H^{0*}_2\\
+\hat e_2 E^0_2  e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k_2 \cdot \mathbf r)} \times
\hat h_1 H^{0*}_1  e^{\mathfrak j (-\omega t + \mathbf k_1 \cdot \mathbf r)} + \hat e_1 E^0_1  e^{\mathfrak j (\omega t - \mathbf k_1 \cdot \mathbf r)} \times \hat h_2 H^{0*}_2  e^{\mathfrak j (-\omega t + \mathbf k_2 \cdot \mathbf r)}
\tag{6}$$ or
$$\mathbf S =\hat e_1\times \hat h_1  E^0_1H^{0*}_1 +\hat e_2\times \hat h_2  E^0_2H^{0*}_2\\
+\hat e_2 \times \hat h_1 E^0_2H^{0*}_1  e^{-\mathfrak j (\mathbf {k_2 -k_1})\cdot \mathbf r)} + \hat e_1 \times \hat h_2 E^0_1H^{0*}_2  e^{\mathfrak j (\mathbf {k_2-k_1}) \cdot \mathbf r}
\tag{7}$$

Now $\hat e_{1,2}\times \hat h_{1,2}=\hat k_{1,2}$ and therefore
$$ \mathbf S = \sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}}\left(\hat k_1 |E^0_1|^2 +\hat k_2 |E^0_2|^2\right) +\mathbf R
\tag{8}$$ where the vector $\mathbf R $ is defined by $$\mathbf R = \sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}}\left(\hat e_2 \times \hat h_1 E^0_2E^{0*}_1  e^{-\mathfrak j (\mathbf {k_2 -k_1})\cdot \mathbf r)} + \hat e_1 \times \hat h_2 E^0_1E^{0*}_2  e^{\mathfrak j (\mathbf {k_2-k_1}) \cdot \mathbf r}\right)\tag{9}.$$

In eq (8) the first two terms are the Poynting vectors of the individual plane waves pointing in their respective propagating directions, resp. The remaining term represented by the vector $\mathbf R$ is the interference term between the two waves. Notice that the frequency term falls out so (8) is indeed a true time average but because the waves point in different directions it has both an active, real, and a reactive, imaginary, term, the latter being in time quadrature relative to the former.

The interference term $\mathbf R$ depends both on the relative directions, $\hat e_1 \times \hat h_2$ and $\hat e_2 \times \hat h_1 $, and relative time phases, $E^0_1E^{0*}_2$ and $E^0_2E^{0*}_1$, of the two  waves and it is plane periodic in a pair of opposite directions $\pm (\mathbf {k_2-k_1})$.

Comment: Thank you very much.  My follow-up question is,  under what circumstances can be neglect $\vec R$?  For instance,  if we average $\vec R$ over all space, it vanishes, as long as $\vec k_1 \neq \vec k_2$.  Perhaps it is negligible whenever $\vec R$ is integrated over a region (whose dimensions are) much larger than $\frac{1}{||\vec k_1 - \vec k_2||}$.  Are there some upper-bounds on such an average? Hopefully, the bound can incorporate the impact of $\left(\hat e_1 \times \hat h_2\right)$ as well....

Comment: I do not think it is ever negligible unless they are nearly orthogonal to each other. Since $|\hat e_{1,2}|=|\hat h_{1,2}|=1$ the various terms have size $|E^0_{1}|^2$, $|E^0_{2}|^2$, $|E^0_{1}E^0_{2}|$, multiplied by the sine angle between $\hat e_1$ and $\hat h_2$ so if say $|E^0_{1}|^2 \ll |E^0_{2}|^2$ you still have the mixed term to deal with. Since these are plane waves the interference term is also homogeneous aside form the spatial fluctuation with periodcity  $\frac{1}{|\mathbf k_1-\mathbf k_2|}$

Comment: Do you agree that the spatial average of $\vec R$ over all space (all of $\mathbb{R}^3$) is zero (whenever $\vec k_1 \neq \vec k_2$)?  Or am I missing something there as well?

Comment: yes, that average is zero, it is a "sinusoid" after all, and this is how energy is conserved globally.

Comment: So, if we average $\vec R$ over a large sphere, doesn't the average approach zero as the radius $A$ of the sphere goes to infinity?  Perhaps at a rate proportional to $\frac{1}{||\vec k_1 - \vec k_2|| A}$?

Comment: So, if we average $\vec R$ over a large sphere, doesn't the average approach zero as the radius $A$ of the sphere goes to infinity?  Perhaps at a rate proportional to $\frac{1}{||\vec k_1 - \vec k_2|| A}$?

Comment: I think just on dimensional basis as $A \to \infty$ the error relative to the total real power deviating from zero will be $\mathcal O \left(\tfrac{1}{|\mathbf {k_1-k_2|}^2A}\right)$